# Where is the `sdk` command installed for sdkman

Tags: linux, bash, sdkman

I just installed [sdkman](http://sdkman.io/) for installing grails on my machine (MacOS). When I run `which sdk` command I don't get any output. But when I run the `sdk help` command the shell is able to resolve it and give the right output. I checked all the directories mentioned in $PATH environment variable but I could not find any executable `sdk`. So my question is how is shell able to resolve the `sdk` command?

Note: I also checked in Ubuntu and I see the same behavior.

[image]
[image]

Comment: `which` is almost never the right command. Use `type` instead

Comment: Thank you! Apparently its a function defined in a source file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. So I found it out. As @that-other-guy mentioned in the comment above, I used `type -a` instead of `which`, which showed me that it was a function defined.

Answer (score 4):

As you mentioned correctly "sdk" is not a command, its a declared function created by sdkman-main.sh (in ~/.sdkman/src) once called from ~/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh

This is the reason why the [installation page of sdkman](https://sdkman.io/install) asks for appending the following steps in the .bash_profile which declares this function each time the bash profile is loaded :

#THIS MUST BE AT THE END OF THE FILE FOR SDKMAN TO WORK!!!

[[ -s "/home/dudette/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh" ]] && source "/home/dudette/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"

This is also the reason "which" command doesn't pick it up as it checks for the installed commands on the linux PATH

Comment: Why must it be at the end of the file? Why can't I add other things to PATH after it?