# "sdk command is not found " is coming the terminal

Tags: sdkman

I installed sdkman in my mac machine and after completion of installation steps and when I tried for sdk to install lazybones in my computer, I am getting error as "sdk command is not found". If anybody have any solution, please let me know.

Comment: Reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44988259/where-is-the-sdk-command-installed-for-sdkman?rq=1 I would say restart your terminal (or your mac)

Answer (score 45):

Very simple in case you use  MAC & OH MY ZSH

step 1:

```
vim ~/.zshrc
```

step 2:(Add at the end of the file)

```
source ~/.bash_profile;
```

step 3:(Execution shell)

```
> source ~/.bash_profile
```

You can use sdkman :
➜  sdk

We periodically need to update the local cache. Please run:

```
$ sdk update
```

---

BINGO!!!

Answer (score 39):

you should append those two lines inside your .bash_profile file.

Usually located in your $HOME Tap `nano $HOME/.bash_profile` and then append those two lines at the end the file using your prefered editor (nano,vim..):

```
# SDK Man replaced GVM. Using for Groovy, Gradle, and Maven Version Management
export SDKMAN_DIR="$HOME/.sdkman"
[[ -s "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh" ]] && source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
```

you can refer to this link: https://www.bonusbits.com/wiki/HowTo:Install_SDKMan_on_MacOS_or_Linux

Comment: I had sdkman installed and working for quite a while. Today it ran into error "-bash: sdk: command not found". Running the command above in terminal fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: Oh no no, don't add that to bash profile. These two lines, if installation is bad, tend to close immediately terminal session so the guy will never be able to login again. And this SDKMAN is piece of non working software, one of the worst setups I've seen. Untill they make it working with yum or apt-get no respect from my side. Caused me serious issues on corporate server. Lame !

Comment: However - instead of curl -s, curl -k worked for me in the first step. Then other steps worked fine, except I had to check other downloaded scripts and replace -s to -k as I was getting "'SDKMAN_CANDIDATES_CSV=$(curl -s "${SDKMAN_SERVICE}/candidates/all")': command failed with exit code 60." -Give us YUM gentlement please !

Comment: Wanting to add to this. In my case, it appears that attempting to install sdkman with `curl` resulted in it concatenating those lines into `~/.zshrc` at the bottom of the file. Issue is, the location I have set up is `~/.zsh/.zshrc`. So worth a check. I stumbled across it by accident because I ran `vi ~/.zshrc` instead of my usual filepath. To avoid issues like this, it may be good to create a symbolic link there.

Answer (score 20):

Try this,

Step-1:

```
curl -s https://get.sdkman.io | bash
```

Step-2:

```
source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
```

Comment: Centos 7 - step gets an empty file. I had to get all stuff from GIT repo. This setup is a joke. Yum, apt-get looks more serious approach but that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

If you already installed SDK please close the terminal and open again.

if you haven't installed it open your terminal & write

```
curl -s https://get.sdkman.io | bash
```

Answer (score 2):

Follow up from @niels's answer on win10, I got `/home/<my_user_name>/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh:162: command not found: __sdkman_echo_debug` because the `find` command was coming from `windows/system32`, as I do `where find` gives me:

```
where find
/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32/find
/usr/bin/find
```

So make sure you didn't mess up with Cgywin's default `$PATH`. By default, cygwin's bash has `/usr/bin/` in front of windows's `system32` folder.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add to the solution provided by @Bachiri Taoufiq Abderrahman.

But one needs to verify which shell he/she is using, run `echo $0` to verify the name of the shell.

And based on if its zsh or bash edit `~./zprofile` or `~/.bash_profile` files.

And add the following lines

`# SDK Man replaced GVM. Using for Groovy, Gradle, and Maven Version Management export SDKMAN_DIR="$HOME/.sdkman" [[ -s "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh" ]] && source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"`

Make sure that these are added at the end of the page or that there is no more entry in the file after this particular entry

Answer (score -1):

If you have the problem at windows: On windows mostly the find-command isn't found. Add in .bashrc the following
`export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH`

this ensures that the linux find is used instead of the windows one.

Answer (score -1):

I resolved it problem configuring the default version of gradle with it command:`sdk install gradle && sdk default gradle`